# Azure App Service Plan Change Azure Web App

Tags: powershell, azure, azure-app-service-plans

I have created a new web app using powershell with this command.

```
new-AzureRMResourceGroupDeployment
```

Now I am looking to change app service plan for the web app from free to shared/standard etc.

having read articles

https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/azure-web-sites-web-hosting-plans-in-depth-overview/

It's not possible to create empty app service plan. so what is the best way to achieve this. One possibility is to change my current app service to Standard. but it will then mean all other web apps in the same service plan will be having the standard plan as well.. How do I update just my web apps app service pricing tier through powershell or otherwise.

Answer (score 0):

In Azure AppService, if you upgrade the app service plan, it will affect all the web apps, api apps, mobile and logic apps in the same plan.

If you don't want that to happen, then you need to put your web app in its own app service plan.

Answer (score 0):

You can create an empty app service plan.  In the Azure Portal, select App Service Plans on the left.  You can click Add, and create an Empty plan.

They key to what you are looking to do is ensure the new App Service plan is 
 1. in the same physical location as the one you are moving from
 2. in the same resource group as the one you are moving from

Then there is an option in the Web App under Settings for "Change App Service Plan".  You will see your new App Service Plan you can move it there.  *As soon as you click the new Service Plan, you app will move, there is no 'click OK to continue'*

In the link you posted, check for the title "Move an app to a different App Service plan"

If you need a new Resource Group, or physical location you are SOL, you need to do a manual move.